# How to set transparent border color for entry control in forms using renderer

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, border

Am using entry control and I need a transparent border color, so used render to achieve the same, but a border is always displayed. How to overcome this.

```
   <local:EntryExt Text="1500"></local:EntryExt>

   public class EntryExt : Entry
   {

   }

  public class EntryExtRenderer : EntryRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
        }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Which doc are you following? Have you defined the class in each platform project?

Comment: Any trouble also for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the border, you can set the `BorderStyle` to `UITextBorderStyle.None`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace App650.iOS
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```